# Start a service and return a value

Tags: android

I Started some service from the OnReceive and When the service will end i want to get some value from that service back into the OnReceive()..

thats my code :

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
            for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
            }

            //show first message
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            String s=smsMessage[0].getMessageBody();
            //START A SERVICE
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,Lineeq.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("message",s); 
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

//Here i need to get a value from the service

```
            abortBroadcast();


        }


                                  any ideas?
                                  Thanks.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BroadcastReceiver` will be gone a millisecond or two after `onReceive()` returns. You cannot return a result from the service, let alone somehow block the `onReceive()` method waiting for it.

Also, bear in mind that `abortBroadcast()` is useless [starting with Android 4.4](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html), as you cannot abort the SMS broadcast.

Comment: So after the data will be gone to the service where it will go next? I think you got me wrong... i edited the question ( " get some value from that service back into the OnReceive()"..

Comment: @mynavy: I do not know what "it" is. `onReceive()` will return. The `BroadcastReceiver` instance will be released by the framework and eventually will be garbage-collected. Sometime after that, the service will run and do something.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to deal with it ? After the android device will get the sms message i need that his device will Calculate some equation with the data he got by sms and it will be in the background service...

Comment: ahhhh... I got it wrong... The service that i'd started will run on the receiving side device or the sender device?

Comment: @mynavy: It will run wherever the code that is in your question gets run. I presume that this is "the receiving side device". Delegating some work from the receiver to a service is fine. However, if your app is relying upon `abortBroadcast()`, then your app needs to be rewritten to get rid of that dependency, as you cannot abort the SMS broadcast on Android 4.4+.

Comment: Thanks.. I dont have a problem with abordBroadcast... the sms contains only coordinates... you see my problem is this : I have an app that should send coordinates by sms to another user.. Now in the receiving side I need to get coordinates from him untill his coordinates will be equal to the sms coordinates thats all i need ... So i created a service that will do this and when he will find that ther's equally strings the app will send sms back to the sender.. Thats why i need the value back.. to know when to send the sms back to the sender.. hope you can understand.

Comment: @mynavy: Have the service send the reply SMS.

Comment: Hah Thanks man I just thought about it now :D ... I will try !

Comment: Ok i tryied it but i had a problem... Is it possible to send a string from the service that i'd started to an activity and still the activity will run in the receiving side?

Comment: @mynavy: If I understand you correctly, use a message bus: `LocalBroadcastManager`, Square's Otto, greenrobot's EventBus, etc.